# attempting to return a range of words in a string using regex java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to return a range of words in string using regular expressions but i am lost in between the lines of doing it. This is my attempt

```
private static final String REGEX = "\\hello";
       private static final String INPUT = "I love holidays hello how are you today during summer";


public static void main( String args[] ) {
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
          Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);   // get a matcher object
          int count = 0;

          while(m.find()) {
             count++;
             System.out.println("Match number "+count);
             System.out.println("start(): "+m.start());
             System.out.println("end(): "+m.end());

             System.out.println("value of m >> "+m);//to print >>> hello how are you
```

Does anyone know how I can return this word **hello how are you** from the string using regex

Comment: could you explain why you expect to get those words? What are the conditions to stop matching the words?

Comment: Your expression would match `\hello` and only that. Do you mean `hello` and any 3 words that follow it?

Comment: @Thomas I mean to start where ever it finds hello and stop wherever it finds you in a string

Comment: @jhamon The condition to stop wherever it finds you is my challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the requirement is to start at `hello` and end at the first `you` you could use the following expression: `hello.*?you`.

Here `.*?` means you want to match anything but as little as possible. This is meant to stop at the first `you` rather than the the last.

If you want to prevent matches on input where `hello` and `you` are only parts of other words surround them with the word boundary `\b`: `\bhello\b.*?\byou\b`.

If you want to match inside sentences only, i.e. the match should not include `.`, `!` or `?`,  you could use a negative character class like `[^.!?]`, i.e. replace `.*?` with `[^.!?]*?`. Note that inside the character class `.` has a literal meaning, i.e. it is the dot and not the "any character" wildcard.

Comment: Sir please could u illustrate this with examples

Comment: I want the match to include anything within the range of the words from hello to you

Comment: @parker What kind of examples do you need? Normally _you_'d be the one to provide examples for your requirements, which you then could use to check the suggested solutions :)

Comment: From what I have Thomas, the words are group together like this .>>>>> I loveholidayshellohowareyoutodayduringsummer

Comment: Is there a way regular expressions can tackle this, had tried this option but did not work \b: \bhello\b.*?\byou\b

Comment: @parker no, if you have a string of letters without any whitespace you can't use word boundaries. In most regex dialect a "word character" is defined as one of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and hence any sequence of those is considered a word, whether it means anything or not. Thus you'd have to use the original expression `hello.*?you` and extract any meaningful words out of the match using something else. Regex can't help you. Btw, why do you have such a string in the first place?